# JQuery Post Attachment return Data

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code which works great.

```
$.post('file.php?do=getLastFile',null,function(attachment){

    //do something - optional

},'json');
```

My problem is that I need to get an alert returning what was the return of file.php.

How can I modify this code so I can get an alert returning the data?

Answer (score 0):

You already have everything up and running, you just need the `alert`-part.

According to the docs, the third argument for `$.post` is the callback-method that fires when the ajax-call was successfully completed. The first argument in this method is the data (i.e whatever the file you called outputted). Simply alerting this will display the content the file outputs.

```
$.post('file.php?do=getLastFile', null, function(data) {
    alert(data);
},'html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **[ajax success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**

```
$.post('file.php?do=getLastFile',null,function(returnData){

   if(returnData.fileName){

    alert(returnData.fileName);
   }

},'json');
```